# MongoDb : Mongoose add elements from different collection to another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I am a newbie in MongoDb and have been using mongoose for backend. Unfortunately I am stuck with this problem where I want elements from ItemModel to to be present as array in CartModel, and the user can delete and add more items to that cart.

Here is my code for CartModel:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item');
//cart id
//cart name
//cart total cost
//cart items
let cartSchema = new Schema(
    {
       cartId :{
           type:String,
           unique:true
       },
       cartName:{
           type:String,
           default:'Item Cart'
       },
       items:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Item'}]
    }
);

mongoose.model('Cart',cartSchema);
```

Here is my ItemModel:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const defaultString = "NOT ASSIGNED";

let itemSchema = new Schema(
    {
        itemId :{
            type:String,
            unique : true
        },
        itemName : {
            type: String,
            default : defaultString
        },
        description : {
            type : String,
            default : defaultString
        },
        soldBy : {
            type : String,
            default : defaultString
        },
        cost : {
            type : Number,
            default : 0
        },
        rating : {
            type : Number,
            default : 1
        },
        category:{
            type : String,
            default : defaultString
        }

    }
);

mongoose.model('Item',itemSchema);
```

Here is the controller method:

```
    let addItemToCart = (req, res) => {

    let itemId = req.itemId;
    let item = getItem(itemId);

    // getting item from ItemModel
    // checking if its null or not, or present or not
    let getItem = (itemId) => {
        let item = null;

        ItemModel.findOne({
            'itemId': req.params.itemId
        }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                item = null;
            } else if (result == undefined || result == null || result == "") {
                item = null;
            } else {
                logger.info("item found successfully", "Item controller:cart add item", 5)
                item = result;
            }
        });

        return item;
    }

    // stuck here, how to add it to CartModel Collection
    CartModel.populate('items.getItem').exec(

    );

}
```

Please help, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So the thing you can do here is mapping the two collection based on the `objectId` or anything like the `itemid` or anything else 
there can be multiple items in a cart but the reverse is not possible so it is

> one to many relation

that is one `Cart` and many `Item` so what you can do is in the item give a cartId and then it will tell that this item belongs to which cart during the checkout so include cartid and then multiple items can have same Cartid 
you can now retrieve all the item as an array using

```
 ItemModel.findOne({
        'CartId': req.params.CartId
    }, (err, result) => {
                return result.json();
      }
```